# Python: Cannot run Selenium with PhantomJS webdriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I have been working on a scrapy project and have used Selenium with Firefox webdriver. Everything works fine. But now I have to use PhantomJS with Selenium. And I am getting a weird error.

Here is the code snippet I am trying to run to test that PhantomJS works with Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage').send_keys("realpython")
driver.find_element_by_id("search_button_homepage").click()
print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

I am getting this error when I run the above code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phantom_try.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 165, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
```

However, everything works fine on the above code if I replace the PhantomJS() initialization line with `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`. The output `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=realpython` is displayed. But no luck with PhantomJS.

```
# Here is the version of tools I am using.
Nodejs v0.10.25
PhantomJS 1.9.8
Scrapy 1.0.5
Selenium 2.53.2
```

I did apt-get install for Nodejs, npm and PhantomJS while pip install for scrapy and selenium. Before this, I also tried installing PhantomJS by downloading source, extracting and copying executable to bin. Also, installed PhantomJS using npm. All methods are showing the same error.

Comment: Have you tried it with PhantomJS 2?

Comment: Nope. But let me try it. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Do I have to uninstall phantomjs to install PhantomJS 2?

Comment: Just download phantomjs executable and start phantomjs as `webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/path/to/downloaded/executable/')`

Comment: same error with PhantomJS 2

Comment: Shot in the dark - what if you would downgrade selenium to 2.52: `pip install selenium==2.52`?

Comment: I fixed it by using phantomjs version 2.1.1